# Como puedo mejorar el rendimiento de pasar filas de una tabla a otra sin que se dupliquen filas?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una `tablaA` y una `tablaB` en *html*; por medio de *js* selecciono una fila de la `tablaA` y la paso a la `tablaB`.

El problema es cuando selecciono todas las filas de la `tablaA` y las paso a la `tablaB`, porque se demora más de 25 segundos en pasar 1500 filas.

Esto ocurre por dos razones:

1. Solo necesito pasar algunas celdas de una fila de la `tablaA`. Para esto paso celda por celda de la `tablaA` a la `tablaB`.
2. Antes de insertar una nueva fila, pregunto si esa fila existe en la `tablaB`, para que no se duplique.

¿Cómo puedo lograr esta funcionalidad sin que se demore tanto tiempo?.

Envió código de la función que pasa todas las filas de la `tablaA` a la `tablaB`:

```
function agregarTodoATablaSecond(nColumnas) {

    tbodyTablaFirst = $('#first > tbody > tr');
    tablaSecond = document.getElementById("tablaSecond").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    $(tbodyTablaFirst).each(function (index) {

        //if (index != 0 && index != 1) {
        var idFilaTablaSeconds = 'ts' + document.getElementById($(tbodyTablaFirst)[index].id).id
        if (document.getElementById(idFilaTablaSeconds) == null) {
            var id = $(tbodyTablaFirst)[0].id
            var row = tablaSecond.insertRow();
            row.setAttribute('id', idFilaTablaSeconds);
            row.setAttribute('class', 'sinGuardar');
            row.style = "background: khaki;";
            // Obtenemos los campos de la nueva fila


            var filaSelecion = $(tbodyTablaFirst)[index]

            // Agregamos una celda o campo

            var campo = null;
            var cell = null;
            var newCheckBox = document.createElement('input');
            newCheckBox.type = 'checkbox';
            newCheckBox.className = 'selected_Ts'
            cell = row.insertCell(0);

            cell.appendChild(newCheckBox);

            $(filaSelecion.children).each(function (index) {
                if (index != 0 && index <= nColumnas) {
                    campo = document.createTextNode(filaSelecion.children[index].innerText);
                    cell = row.insertCell(index);
                    cell.appendChild(campo);
                }
            })
        }
        //}
    });
    seleccionarTodosCheckBox()
    ocultarMostrarControles()
}
```

Comment: Creo que la demora esta basada mas en la inyeccion del nuevo child, seria bueno que adjuntaras que libreria estas usando para la tabla, o si es que estas haciendo el proceso con js puro.

Comment: Las tablas son HTML no utilizo ninguna librería, y si lo estoy haciendo con js. Cuando una persona selecciona el botón "Seleccionar todo " se ejecuta la función agregarTodoATablaSecond(ncolumnas) que esta en js y que recibe un numero de columnas por que no siempre se pasan todas las columnas de las tablaA.

Comment: has depronto notado que cuando esta ejecutando el proceso de pasar los datos la pagina se bloquea? es decir, se traba? o sigue funcionando los demas botones y todo normal.

Comment: Es correcto @JulianCuevas se bloquean todos los botones, a veces sale el mensaje del navegador y pregunta desea esperar?

Comment: usa un worker, ya que el proceso en la repetitiva hace que la ui se bloquee, de esta forma podras añadir de manera controlada todos los items a la tabla